# Change value of data-toggle depends on checkbox value on page load

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create an customer order page in which checkbox is used to show product delivery status using bootstrap `data-toggle`. This `data-toggle` is disable in default.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="toggle" value="${customerOrder.deliver}" disabled data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Deliver" data-off="Not Deliver"/></td>
```

The problem is when page load, `data-toggle` value not change depends on `checkbox value`. Do I need to use `jQuery` to check `checkbox value` or is bootstrap can handle `data-toggle` value to on or off its value.

Thank you very much for your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup to:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1"/>
```

where "collapse" is the class of the div you want to toggle and "collapse1" its id:

```
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 ... your code...
</div>
```